# Versioning translatable entities in Doctrine (symfony2)

Tags: php, version-control, orm, symfony, doctrine-orm

What would be the best way to integrate versioning system of some entity which uses gedmo translatable behaviour?

Gedmo Loggable does not seem to work like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="Alef\JobOffersBundle\Repository\JobOfferRepository")
 * @ORM\Table(name="alef_job_offer")
 * @Gedmo\Loggable
 */
class JobOffer implements Loggable, Translatable, UserOwnerInterface {

    /**
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    protected $id;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Alef\UserBundle\Entity\User")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="id_user", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    protected $user;

    /**
     * @var datetime $created
     *
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="create")
     * @ORM\Column(name="created", type="datetime")
     */
    protected $created;

    /**
     * @var datetime $updatedAt
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="datetime")
     * @Gedmo\Timestampable(on="update")
     */
    protected $updatedAt;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Versioned
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(name="title", type="string", length=255)
     */
    protected $title;

    /**
     *
     * @Gedmo\Versioned
     * @Gedmo\Translatable
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text")
     */
    protected $description;

    [...]
```

I get empty `data` field in `ext_logged_entries`.

Or maybe there is a better way to store translatable and versioned entities? Maybe not using Gedmo doctrine extensions?

Comment: Looks fine to me. Have you tried Stof's DoctrineExtensionBundle? https://github.com/stof/StofDoctrineExtensionsBundle

Comment: Take a look at http://gediminasm.org/article/loggable-behavioral-extension-for-doctrine2 and scroll down to the comments, there's a comment made by @Birko that explains this, but I'm having trouble getting it to work perfectly. The solution is a bit tricky in my opinion.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possilbe to use Loggable and Translatable togetther.
Have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18301727/2059504).