# Symfony 2 : Using Translatable and Loggable together

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Im working on a multilingual-news publisher in symfony2 using the doctrine extensions:-

Translatable and Loggable

Although I have them both working with a default english posts (i.e logs on update) I cant get edited translations to be logged... the record is inserted into 'ext_log_entries' table but i only get an empty serialised array.

Does anyone have any ideas or examples? I've pretty much followed the git-hub guide for both extensions.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to do the same thing earlier. I had to find out it is not possible to use these two things together, you have to implement it for yourselfe.

I did it this way:
Text.php

```
use Gedmo\Mapping\Annotation as Gedmo;
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="text")
 * @ORM\Entity
 * @Gedmo\Loggable
 */
class Text
{
    /** @ORM\Id @ORM\GeneratedValue @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
    private $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="class", type="string") */
    private $class;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="field", type="string") */
    private $field;

    /** @ORM\Column(name="key_id", type="integer") */
    private $key_id;

    /**
    * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Language")
    * @ORM\JoinColumns({
    *   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="lang_id", referencedColumnName="id")
    * })
    */
    private $lang;

    /**
     * @Gedmo\Versioned
     * @ORM\Column(name="text", type="text")
     */
    private $text;

    ...getter setter...
}
```

Language.php

```
use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;


/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="language")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Language {

    /** @ORM\Id @ORM\GeneratedValue @ORM\Column(type="integer") */
    private $id;

    /** @var  @ORM\Column(name="language", type="string") */
    private $language;
... getter setter ....
```

Now I wrote a service for managing these:
TextManager.php

```
/**
 * @param $object
 * @param $field
 * @param $langKey
 * @return Text
 *
 * gets the existing text for the object
 * if it does not exist, it creates a new one
 */
public function setupText($object, $field, $langKey){
    $lang = $this->langRepo->findOneBy(array("language" => $langKey));

    $txt = $this->textRepo->findOneBy(array(
        'class' => get_class($object), 'field' => $field,
        'lang' => $lang, 'key_id' => $object->getId()
    ));
    if($txt != null){
        return $txt;
    }

    $txt = new Text();
    $txt->setClass(get_class($object));
    $txt->setField($field);
    $txt->setKeyId($object->getId());
    $txt->setLang($lang);

    return $txt;
}

/**
 * @param $object
 * @param $field
 * @param $langKey
 * @return mixed
 * gives you the text object or false if not found
 */
public function getText($object, $field, $langKey){
    $lang = $this->langRepo->findOneBy(array("language" => $langKey));

    $txt = $this->textRepo->findOneBy(array(
        'class' => get_class($object), 'field' => $field,
        'lang' => $lang, 'key_id' => $object->getId()
    ));

    if ($txt == null){
        return false;
    }

    return $txt;
}
```

In your controller you can now to things like that:
to get an text object in ohter version

```
$logRepo = $em->getRepository('Gedmo\Loggable\Entity\LogEntry'); // we use default log entry class
$text = $textManager->setupText($object, 'abouttext', 'de');
$logRepo->revert($text, 1); //1 is the version you would like to have
$text->getText(); //version 1 text
```

to make a new text object

```
$text = $textManager->setupText($object, 'otherfield', 'fr');
$text->setText("your super text");
$em->persist($text);
$em->flush();
```

Hope it helps you, and if you have any question, dont mind asking.